# How to rotate menu 180 degrees android

Tags: java, android

Okay so I am developing an app that will have to players playing against each other. The two players will be opposite each other so I want to be able to the rotate the activity 180 degrees when it is one of the players moves. So far I have been able to do it by overriding any views onDraw() method and applying the rotation there. So I want to have a menu that is possible to rotate by 180 degrees depending on the which players move it is. So how would I rotate the menu by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how would I rotate the menu by 180 degrees.

You wouldn't. You would not use the built-in options menu, but rather create your own menu with your own views that you draw as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

Comment: But since animation doesn't actually change the position of things, just how they look visually, so it will make menu item presses call the wrong selected item. Not sure if i explained that to well.